# Synchronous issue to save a file into GridFS - Node.JS/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to save a profile photo from a social network as Facebook in my "fs.files" and "fs.chunks" as well, I can achieve this but the way I found to do it is not properly one.

My steps are:

1. Make user logon on the Facebook using Passport;
2. Saving the picture file on the disk (an internal application folder);
3. Open and read the picture file and store it on the properly collections (files and chunks from Mongo).

The problem happens between steps 2 and 3, because saving a file on the disk in this case is not the best idea and a synchronous issue and latency happens when attempt to store it on the DB.

I had used `setTimeout` javascript function to make it happens. But it is so bad, I know. I wonder to know somehow a way to get some kind of file stream and store it directly on the  GridFS or to make the the actual process more efficient:

**The codes:**

Get the picture from an URL and save it (disk step)

```
// processing image 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.uid + '/picture';
// facebook -> disk
var userProfilePhoto = user.provider + '_' + user.uid + '.png';

request(user.photoURL)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(configApp.temp_files + userProfilePhoto));
```

Get the picture saved on the disk and store it on the GridFS

```
setTimeout(function() {
    mongoFile.saveFile(user, true, userProfilePhoto, mimeType.mime_png, 
        function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                user.save();
            }
        }
    );
}, 5000);
```

Unfortunately I had to use `setTimeout` to make it possible, without it the mongo just insert on "fs.files" and skip "fs.chunks" because the file is not ready yet - seems to be not saved yet.

Comment: What Node driver are you using?  The standard Node driver GridFS docs are here: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html

Comment: I'm using the default mongo driver instead of mongoose or even mongojs for GridFS. The problem I'm facing is about the synchronous between write the picture file on the disk and save it later to DB.

Comment: The code above works to, but still terrible because there is two things right there: 1 - I have once to write file down to the disk; 2 - I have to open and read this file from the disk and write to DB. I would like a straight way to do that, more efficient and without the workaround code I've created to tease the synchronous issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

I replaced request plugin for [http-get](https://npmjs.org/package/http-get) so when the file is ready I can store it in MongoDB.